# Formula that is divided only by Wagstaff primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test, lucas-lehmer-test

Here is what I observed :

Let's put the number $W_p = \frac{2^p+1}{3}$ where $p$ is prime and $W_p$ is a Wagstaff number.

Let's put the formula $\omega_p = (\frac{1}{2} (1 + i \sqrt7))^{(\frac{2^{p - 1} - 1}{3})} + (\frac{1}{2} (1 - i \sqrt7))^{(\frac{2^{p - 1} - 1}{3})}$ when $p$ is a prime number $>3$

Then it seems than $W_p$ divides $\omega_p$ only if $W_p$ is prime.

For example :

- $W_5 = 11$ divides $\omega_5 = 11$
- $W_7 = 43$ divides $\omega_7 = 2795$
- $W_{11} = 683$ divides $\omega_{11} = -2740121063461600091886597704982460332288405576168469$
- $W_{29}$ doesn't divide $\omega_{29}$ the first non-Wagstaff prime.

I've checked until $p = 31$ and it seems it's true.

So I have two questions :

Do you think this is possible to make a primality test like Lucas-Lehmer test for this ? I tried to find a sequence but I didn't find it for the moment.

And if yes, is there a way to prove it ?

Comment: Have you proved that if $W_p$ is prime then $W_p$ divides $\omega_p$?  For most primality tests, that's the easier of the two implications, and the converse requires some special properties of the prime (e.g. a partial factorization of $p \pm 1$).

Comment: No, I didn't prove it, I will edit thanks !

Comment: Usually efficient primility proofs require that one of $p-1$ and $p+1$ can be easily factored. This is not the case here. Maybe, you found a kind of probable prime test that might be extremely reliable. But then, a single Miller Rabin test (say with base $3$) could be done as well. We could check how reliable this is upto some limit.

Comment: For an overview of the status of Wagstaff primes , look [here](https://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=67) - apparently no general efficient primality proof is known for those numbers.